# executeTaskAction fails for :app:processDebugResources

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting this error message: Build: build failed --> Run build --> Run tasks --> :app:processDebugResources --> executeTaskAction. The order of the code presented below goes: error message, and then build.gradle(Project), and then build.gradle(app).

This error message has been answered many times before by other StackOverflow users, but none of their proposed solutions have worked for me. Mostly because the versions they use suggest that I fix the "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0" setting in the build.gradle(Project:app), but they have different versions since those posts are from 2+ years ago. I've tried cleaning the project, cleaning the build, rebuilding both the build and the project, adding the "Maven" repository, reinstalling all of the Sdks...nothing has worked for the last three hours.

This is the error message:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. at 



org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTask
Executer.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103) at


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.
execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73) at

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreating
TaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51) at

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.
execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59) at


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCaching
StateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.
execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at 


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTask
Executer.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at 

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFileProperties
TaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.
java:44)
at

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputs
Executer.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at 

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactState
TaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at 

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActions
Executer.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at 


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter
.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at

org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTask
Executer.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at 


org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTask
Executer.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$Event
FiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at 

org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$
RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperation
Executor.java:336)
at 

org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runnable
BuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at 


org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at 

org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$Event
FiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$Event
FiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$Task
ExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at


 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$Task
ExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at 


 org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$Task
ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$Task
ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan
.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.
executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at 

org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$Task
ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at 

org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAnd
RecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at 

org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run
(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at

 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.

run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$Managed
ThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: 
    Android resource linking failed
Output:  

/Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1
    /app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/
    debug/processDebugResources/r/com/example/myname
    /synthesizer1/R.java: error: invalid symbol name 
    'com.example.firstname_lastname.synthesizer:id/null'.

Command: /Users/myname/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2- 
 3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/d5f72cb60485350dcf6302aeab61e4d4/aapt2-3.2.1- 
 4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android- 
28/android.jar\
        --manifest\

/Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1
/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/
  processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\


 /Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1/app
 /build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources
/out/resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\

  @/Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1/
app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources- 
list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\

  /Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1/app
/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebug
Resources/r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.myname.synthesizer1\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\

  /Users/myname/Downloads/AndroidProjects/MediaLib/Synthesizer1/app/
build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors


Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
    at 

com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2
DaemonImpl.kt:177)
at 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.
kt:103)
at 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$Leased
AaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
at 
com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(Android
Builder.java:823)
at 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroid
ResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResources
Task.java:525)
at 

com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroid
ResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask
.java:275)
at

 com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.task
Action(IncrementalTask.java:106)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethod
AccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at

org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at 

org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction
.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at 

 org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.
 execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at 

 org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction
 .execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at 

 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTask
 Executer$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at 

org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runnable
BuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at 

org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$Runnable
BuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at 

 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.
execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at 

 org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run
 (DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at 

 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
 .executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at 

 org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter
 .executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
     ... 33 more
```

Here is what is currently in my build.gradle(Project):

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


   // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

allprojects {
    repositories {
       google()
         maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is what's in my build.gradle(Module: app);

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.artchen_wei.synthesizer"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- 
  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test:runner
           :1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.
           espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 }
```

I'm trying to get all steps of the build to run effectively so that I can complete this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your error message (kind of hidden in the big stack trace, but should be 
 at the top in the IDE sync window):

> error: invalid symbol name 
>       'com.example.firstname_lastname.synthesizer:id/null'.

That means somewhere in your resources you are defining an ID with the name "null". It can either be in any XML file with the `+id/null` construction, or explicitly in the values folder with `<id name="null ... />` or `<item type='id' name='null' ... />`.

Search your project for the word `null` and you should be able to find it. Since the word `null` is an illegal name (i.e. you can't use it as a variable name in Java), just rename it to something else, like `not_null`. Make sure to not use any of the other illegal keywords, like `public`, `private`, `final`, `default` etc.